# I am not being notified when my question is answered

Tags: support

I have opted to be notified when my question is responded to even if not a full answer
but I have received not such notification??

Comment: At least for old MathOverflow, the emails didn't come instantly- sometimes I would see the answer by coming here, and get the email a couple of hours later. That said, good to check these things anyway.

Answer (score 9):

The email notifications per question were removed in the SE 2.0 engine - however they were replaced by getting *all* your notifications in a single email batched up at an interval of your preference.  You can set this preference on every page!  Here's how:

Click email settings in the Stack Exchange dropdown:

[image: email settings]

Then enter the email you want them sent to, and the interval you want (we only send if there was something, and you didn't already read your inbox on any site):

[image: time preference]

We will send you a one-time email verification (to prevent spamming random people - we make sure *you* asked for these emails) then you'll receive your inbox updates *only* if you missed anything.  You can opt out of the emails at any time by changing the preference of via a one-click link in the footer of each email.